# Temporarily disabling mouse events after showing window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, appkit

[image]

When typing URL in Safari window it's child suggestions window will appear. It temporarily hides and disables the mouse input. How is this done?

I have a project (link below) which implemented location suggesting + mouse hide. I don't know how to disable mouse to stop picking suggestions when mouse position is above the suggestion window while typing (it always selects some of those entries).

I know the hidden magic should be something about `NSTrackingArea`

```
/* Properly creates a tracking area for an image view.
*/
- (id)trackingAreaForView:(NSView *)view {
    // make tracking data (to be stored in NSTrackingArea's userInfo) so we can later determine the imageView without hit testing
    NSDictionary *trackerData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:view, kTrackerKey, nil];

    NSRect trackingRect = [[self.window contentView] convertRect:view.bounds fromView:view];
    NSTrackingAreaOptions trackingOptions = NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInActiveApp;
    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:trackingRect options:trackingOptions owner:self userInfo:trackerData];

    return trackingArea;
}

/* The mouse is now over one of our child image views. Update selection and send action.
*/
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)event {
    HighlightingView *view = [(NSDictionary*)[event userData] objectForKey: kTrackerKey];
    [self userSetSelectedView:view];
}
```

Project:
https://github.com/xhruso00/MapkitSearchFieldOSX

Suggestions? How does apple disables mouse input for suggestions (maps...)

PS: I would like to keep highlighting suggestions. Do not want to disable it.

Comment: "How does apple" do you mean in Apple's sample code CustomMenus? It doesn't.

Comment: @WillekeIf you try Maps.app or Safari.app and leave the mouse under the suggestion window it won't fire any mouseEntered: event (not counting the tooltip one, try lldb br set -n "mouseEntered:"). I have no idea how apple is doing the suggestion window

Comment: Maybe they react only to mouseMoved:. Breakpoint hit this  [SGTCompletionTableView mouseMoved:]

Answer (score 0):

Adding `NSTrackingMouseMoved` to `NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited` and remembering which view was under mouseEntered: solved the issue.

```
@interface SuggestionsWindowController() {
    HighlightingView *_mouseEnteredView; //ADDED
}



///* The mouse is now over one of our child image views. Update selection and send action.
//*/
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)event {
    HighlightingView *view = [(NSDictionary*)[event userData] objectForKey: kTrackerKey];
    _mouseEnteredView = view; //ADDED
    //[self userSetSelectedView:view];
}

//ADDED
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)event {
    //userData is not attached to event and it will crash if one accesses it
    //HighlightingView *view = [(NSDictionary*)[event userData] objectForKey: kTrackerKey];

    [self userSetSelectedView:_mouseEnteredView];
}

/* The mouse has left one of our child image views. Set the selection to no selection and send action
*/
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent*)event {
    [self userSetSelectedView:nil];
    _mouseEnteredView = nil; //ADDED
}
```